# how to make objects of different entity classes and store record in database MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

its my controller method.
it returns null values.
any suggestions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatBranch()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            var contactinfo = new ContactInfo();
            db.ContactInfo.Add(contactinfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var contctid = contactinfo.ContactID;
            var addressinfo = new Address();
            db.Address.Add(addressinfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var addid = contactinfo.ContactID;

            var branchInfo = new Branch { ContactID = contctid, AddressID = addid, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]), UpdatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]) , UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now};
            db.Branches.Add(branchInfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

//int contact id returns int value, int add also returns an int value. but remaining attributes are passing null values .
```

Answer (score 0):

its done.
there was a coding error.
var addid = addressinfo.AddressID.